# Frobenius actions on de Rham cohomology, clarify questions on a paper of Kedlaya

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I am reading the paper ["$p$-adic cohomology: from theory to practice"](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/2007/KedlayaNotes11Mar.pdf) by K. S. Kedlaya. I have several naive questions about section 2: Frobenius action on de Rham cohomology. As a physicist, I lack proper backgrounds needed for this paper, and I am very grateful if someone could explain my questions carefully.

**Question 1**: In the remark 2.1.3 (page 16), (in the notation of this paper), a morphism $\overline{f}:(\overline{X},\overline{Z}) \rightarrow (\overline{X}',\overline{Z}')$ functorially induces a homomorphism 
\begin{equation}
H^i_{dR}(X',Z') \rightarrow H^i_{dR}(X,Z)
\end{equation}
why do we want $\overline{f}$ induces this morphism which is at a higher level (since there is a morphism we already easily get $H^i_{dR}(\overline{X}',\overline{Z}') \rightarrow H^i_{dR}(\overline{X},\overline{Z})$)? Is this because Theorem 2.1.2, i.e. the canonical comparison isomorphism is between $H^i_{dR}(X,Z)$ and $H^i_{crys}(\overline{X},\overline{Z})$?

**Question 2**: I guess the $q$-th power Frobenius map $F_{q}$ is induced by the $\mathbb{F}_q$-algebra homomorphism $A \rightarrow A$ which sends $x$ to $x^q$? The map $F_q$ induces an endomorphism $F_q^*$ of $H^i_{dR}(X,Z)$, under the comparison isomorphism, it induces an endomorphism of $H^i_{crys}(\overline{X},\overline{Z})$. Is $F_q^*$ sent to ation of geometric Frobenius (the inverse of Frobenius element of $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q/\mathbb{F}_q)$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1, you are correct that the map
$$\bar f^* \colon H^i_{\text{dR}}(X',Z') \to H^i_{\text{dR}}(X,Z)$$
is the one obtained from
$$\bar f^* \colon H^i_{\text{crys}}(\bar X',\bar Z') \to H^i_{\text{crys}}(\bar X,\bar Z)$$
using the comparison isomorphism. This is exactly the point of Remark 2.1.3: it is remarkable that the map $\bar f^*$ on $H^i_{\text{dR}}$ exists, because a priori de Rham cohomology is only functorial for morphisms $f \colon (X,Z) \to (X',Z')$ (think: a lift of $\bar f$).

---

For question 2, note that the geometric Frobenius is not an element of $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb F}_q/\mathbb F_q)$. The composition of geometric Frobenius with arithmetic Frobenius is the absolute Frobenius. What happens is that on étale cohomology, the absolute Frobenius acts trivially, hence geometric Frobenius *acts* as the inverse of arithmetic Frobenius. See for example [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/30316/82179).

In the case of crystalline cohomology, one usually only studies the action of the absolute Frobenius. In the case of a variety over $\mathbb F_q$, the $q$-power Frobenius acts trivially on $\mathbb F_q$, hence geometric $q$-power Frobenius equals absolute $q$-power Frobenius, and the arithmetic $q$-power Frobenius is trivial. I guess one could study the arithmetic $p$-power Frobenius viewed as an element of $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb F_q/\mathbb F_p)$, but this is not usually considered.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add the following points to the answer of R. van Dobben de Bruyn, in order to answer the "why" part of the question "why do we want $\bar f$ to induce this morphism which is at a higher level"?

First, Kedlaya's paper is about $p$-adic cohomology of a variety in characteristic $p$. There is a well-behaved $\ell$-adic cohomology theory coming from étale cohomology when $\ell\neq p$, but some of their good properties are lost when you try to put $\ell=p$. This sort of affairs motivated Grothendieck to introduce crystalline cohomology, later developed by Berthelot, as a better substitute for $p$-adic cohomology.

So, what we are really interested in, is $H_{crys}$.

It turns out, nontrivially, that crystalline cohomology is essentially the de Rham cohomology of a lift to characteristic zero (and it doesn't depend on the lift).

So yes, we are interested in the functorial map in cohomology *of the lift* because this cohomology *of the lift* is a posteriori the thing we were looking for.

(Moreover, in my opinion, this remark is extremely interesting in itself. Namely, the fact that a map between the reductions mod p, even without coming from an actual map between the lifts char 0, it maps *cohomology classes* on the lifts char 0 in a well-defined manner)

Last, not only the $p$-adic étale cohomology, but also the de Rham cohomology mod p is worse-behaved than the crystalline cohomology. I have read [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222326/reference-for-de-rham-cohomology-in-positive-characteristic?rq=1) that the de Rham cohomology mod p just takes $p$ torsion from the crystalline cohomology.

My personal, and incomplete, explanation for why a lift char 0 is preferrable (or more "perfect", if we like to play on words) to the space mod p itself, when you consider $H_{dR}$, is as follows. First, $H_{dR}$ is used to understand the underlying space by considering differentials on it. But when you are in positive characteristic, things mess up and you might lose some important information. As a prototype for this, think of differentiating $x\mapsto x^q$, you get exactly zero. Or viceversa, you cannot find a primitive to $x\mapsto x^{p-1}$ because you lack the ability to divide by $p$.

Comment: I would not call these gadgets "a lift to char 0" - they lives over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z_p$, which is usually called of mixed char. After all, crystalline cohomology is an integral cohomology theory.

Comment: I would guess that the motivation to lift $\mathbb F_p$ to $\mathbb Z_p$ is that, the objects that we are really interested are $\mathbb Z$-schemes. In fact, the derived $\mathbb Z$-de Rham cohomology $\operatorname{dR}_{R/\mathbb Z}$ is not that bad (I was also misled. The $\mathbb F_p$-de Rham cohomology that you have mentioned is $\operatorname{dR}_{R/\mathbb F_p}$). On the other hand, a precise comparison of $\mathbb F_p$-de Rham and crystalline cohomologies is: $R\Gamma_{\mathrm{cris}}(X/\mathbb Z_p)\otimes_{\mathbb Z_p}^{\mathbb L}\mathbb F_p\simeq R\Gamma_{\mathrm dR}(X/\mathbb F_p)$.

Comment: (continued) where $X$ is a smooth $\mathbb F_p$-scheme. I don't know a good reference. [Bhatt's lecture notes about prismatic cohomology](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bhattb/teaching/prismatic-columbia/lecture6-hodge-tate-and-crystalline-comparison.pdf) covered this in Corollary 1.8 of lecture 6.